# Java Graph Help needed with dynamic Edges

Tags: java, arraylist, graph

I'm currently writing a code that's going to be adding neighbors to edges. But due to the nature of the project I won't be knowing how many neighbors one edge is going to have. For instance

```js
verti.vertices[34].adjacencies = new Edge[2];
verti.vertices[41].adjacencies = new Edge[4];
```

as you can see in `new Edge [2]` and `new Edge [4]` I'm declaring the number of neighbors that edge is going to have, however later on in my code when the program is adding the neighbors it might add less neighbors than initially declared which leads to a

> java.lang.NullPointerException

Is there anyway for me to handle this issue with a dynamic range (similar to an Arraylist)?

Comment: First some nitpicking: It should be _adding neighbors to vertices_ right? That happens via `Edge`s. Not adding neighbors to _edges_.

Comment: To be verbally correct, yes. Thank you for the clarification

Comment: Regarding the question, I think you mentioned the solution yourself: Use a List instead of an Array as type for `adjacencies`. (unless there is a hidden reason why you can't change that. It's your code right?)

Comment: I'm actually working on the code with a friend, so some of the design choices are his but we can certainly work on that. The problem is I don't how one would implement an Arraylist with this, if you could present a modified version of the code piece I provided it would be really helpful

Comment: Why do you need to declare before the actual initialization ? Is it because it is part of 2D array ? (A [mcve]  would have saved all those questions and make help more efficient)

Comment: Check [JGrapht](http://jgrapht.org/). I'm amazed why people always write their own graph models when there are libraries like JGrapht out there. (I have no affiliation with JGraphT, just a frequent user of the library.)

Answer (score 0):

An `ArrayList` is as you know the straightest solution to manipulate a collection of objects which the size is dynamic.

Without using that, you have two solutions :

**Solving the issue at its origin and doing it once**

will have to define in the object that contains the array, the actual size of the array.
Similarly to what  `ArrayList` does internally to know the current size.

```
/**
 * The size of the ArrayList (the number of elements it contains).
 *
 * @serial
 */
private int size;
```

You could introduce an `addEdge()` method that adds the `Edge` object to the array and increment the actual size of the array.

```
public class Foo{
  public Edge[] vertices;
  private int size;

  public void addEdge(Edge edge){
     vertices[size++] = edge;
  }
}
```

You could so write :

```
verti.vertices[34].addEdge(new Edge(...));
```

**Adding a guard at each time you want to access to a Edge element**

For example :

```
for (Edge edge : verti.vertices[34].adjacencies ){
   if (edge != null){
     // do something
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have thought about a method similar to this (actually finding the numbers of neighbors that's going to be added and declaring that variable as the size of the array ) but the code is going to have 81 vertices so I was looking for a shorter easier version

Comment: You can let the method to increment for you the current size. You are not constraint to compute it once. Other way : add a guard. I updated with this last point.

Comment: That doesn't really answer OPs problem with dynamic sizing. Any call to `addEdge` would fail with a NPE because `vertices` has not been initialised. How do you initialise it and with how many elements?

Comment: @Jens Hoffmann according to the OP description, the dynamic size is required for Edge array not for vertices array .Whatever, it is not a verifiable example in the question. So free to interpretation I assume.

Comment: @davidxxx That's true, hard to work with 2 lines of code and no context :)